# How to turn NaNs in a data frame into NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, nan, na

I'm hoping and fearing this just has a one line answer, and am embarrassed about having to ask it:

As a result of casting a dataframe using reshape2, I have a large dataframe whose first lines are as follows:

```
  ukgridcode      x       y year     pm10 pm2.5      no2      nox  co so2 ozone benzene
1      56361 460500 1218500 2001 8.583796   NaN 2.375508 3.031918 NaN NaN   NaN     NaN
2      57051 460500 1217500 2001 8.584764   NaN 2.368387 3.022830 NaN NaN   NaN     NaN
3      57052 461500 1217500 2001 8.587392   NaN 2.383438 3.042039 NaN NaN   NaN     NaN
4      57054 463500 1217500 2001 8.590163   NaN 2.455386 3.133869 NaN NaN   NaN     NaN
5      57741 460500 1216500 2001 8.588822   NaN 2.375839 3.032340 NaN NaN   NaN     NaN
6      57742 461500 1216500 2001 8.592360   NaN 2.394949 3.056732 NaN NaN   NaN     NaN
```

I would like to turn each of the NaNs into NAs. So far I've tried:

```
d2 <- d[is.nan(d)] <- NA
d2 <- d[!is.finite(d)] <- NA
d2 <- apply(d, 2, function (x) x[is.nan(x)] <- NA) # also tried row-wise (1)
```

But so far no success.

Solutions gratefully received.

Comment: Why don't you use the `fill` parameter of `dcast`?

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning Wickhamese and will look at the fill argument. The answer below seems to work for now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
d[sapply(d, is.nan)] <- NA


#   ukgridcode      x       y year     pm10 pm2.5      no2      nox co so2 ozone benzene
# 1      56361 460500 1218500 2001 8.583796    NA 2.375508 3.031918 NA  NA    NA      NA
# 2      57051 460500 1217500 2001 8.584764    NA 2.368387 3.022830 NA  NA    NA      NA
# 3      57052 461500 1217500 2001 8.587392    NA 2.383438 3.042039 NA  NA    NA      NA
# 4      57054 463500 1217500 2001 8.590163    NA 2.455386 3.133869 NA  NA    NA      NA
# 5      57741 460500 1216500 2001 8.588822    NA 2.375839 3.032340 NA  NA    NA      NA
# 6      57742 461500 1216500 2001 8.592360    NA 2.394949 3.056732 NA  NA    NA      NA
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.nan(x), NA, x))]
```

Or just look at @Rolands comment

Answer (score 1):

```
d[is.na(d)]<-NA
```

The problem is that `is.nan` has no method for a data frame implemented, but `is.na` has (`is.na.data.frame`). Since `is.na(NaN)` returns TRUE, the above works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 is.nan(d$pm2.5)
 #[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

 d[d=="NaN"] <- NA
 d
 #    ukgridcode      x       y year     pm10 pm2.5      no2      nox co so2 ozone
 #1      56361 460500 1218500 2001 8.583796    NA 2.375508 3.031918 NA  NA    NA
 #2      57051 460500 1217500 2001 8.584764    NA 2.368387 3.022830 NA  NA    NA
 #3      57052 461500 1217500 2001 8.587392    NA 2.383438 3.042039 NA  NA    NA
 #4      57054 463500 1217500 2001 8.590163    NA 2.455386 3.133869 NA  NA    NA
 #5      57741 460500 1216500 2001 8.588822    NA 2.375839 3.032340 NA  NA    NA
 #6      57742 461500 1216500 2001 8.592360    NA 2.394949 3.056732 NA  NA    NA
 #  benzene
 #1      NA
 #2      NA
 #3      NA
 #4      NA
 #5      NA
 #6      NA
```

Comment: hmm interesting... I didn't know that you can do that with `NaN`. I assumed it wouldn't work just like something like `d[d=="NA"] <- 1` won't work

Comment: `NA` is a very strange creature. It's class is `logical` but `NA == "NA"` returns `NA`, while `TRUE` (which class is also `logical`) works `TRUE == "TRUE"` return `TRUE`

Comment: Yes,  class(NaN)#[1] "numeric", but d==NaN doesnot work

Comment: Yes, I know `class(NaN)` is `numeric` this is why compared `NA` with `TRUE` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

if the dataframe is available as a csv file then regex find NaN replace with NA will work in a text editor with regular expressions (e.g. in notepad++ )